# WAR and ERR on npm install

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, npm-install

Mean Stack App template is created
i need to install the app’s dependencies via NPM: 
**npm install

or

npm install --dev

or

npm install --only=dev**

Package.json

```
    {
      "name": "mean",
      "description": "Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js",
      "version": "0.4.0",
      "private": false,
      "author": "2",
      "license": "MIT",
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/meanjs/mean.git"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.10.28",
        "npm": ">=1.4.28"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "grunt",
        "test": "grunt test",
        "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "acl": "~0.4.4",
        "async": "^1.3.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.13.1",
        "bower": "^1.4.1",
        "chalk": "^1.1.0",
        "compression": "^1.5.0",
        "connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
        "connect-mongo": "~0.8.1",
        "consolidate": "~0.13.1",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.3.2",
        "express": "^4.13.1",
        "express-session": "^1.11.3",
        "forever": "~0.14.2",
        "glob": "^5.0.13",
        "grunt": "0.4.5",
        "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
        "helmet": "~0.9.1",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
        "lodash": "^3.10.1",
        "method-override": "^2.3.3",
        "mocha": "~1.20.0",
        "mongoose": "^4.0.6",
        "morgan": "^1.6.1",
        "multer": "0.1.8",
        "node-pre-gyp": "0.6.4",
        "nodemailer": "^1.4.0",
        "passport": "~0.2.2",
        "passport-facebook": "^2.0.0",
        "passport-github": "~0.1.5",
        "passport-google-oauth": "~0.2.0",
        "passport-linkedin": "~0.1.3",
        "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
        "passport-paypal-openidconnect": "^0.1.1",
        "passport-twitter": "^1.0.2",
        "phantomjs": ">=1.9.0",
        "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
        "socket.io": "^1.3.5",
        "swig": "^1.4.2",
        "validator": "^3.41.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "grunt-concurrent": "^2.0.0",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.8.0",
        "grunt-contrib-csslint": "~0.4.0",
        "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.12.3",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.11.2",
        "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.0.1",
        "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.9.2",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.9.1",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
        "grunt-env": "~0.4.4",
        "grunt-karma": "~0.11.2",
        "grunt-mocha-test": "~0.12.7",
        "grunt-ng-annotate": "^1.0.1",
        "grunt-node-inspector": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-nodemon": "~0.4.0",
        "grunt-protractor-runner": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp": "^3.9.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
        "gulp-csslint": "~0.1.5",
        "gulp-cssmin": "~0.1.7",
        "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.2",
        "gulp-karma": "~0.0.4",
        "gulp-less": "^3.0.3",
        "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.0",
        "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
        "gulp-mocha": "^2.1.2",
        "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.0.0",
        "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.3",
        "gulp-protractor": "^1.0.0",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
        "gulp-sass": "^2.0.3",
        "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
        "karma": "~0.12.37",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.2.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~0.4.2",
        "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.6",
        "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6",
        "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.2",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.0",
        "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.2.0",
        "run-sequence": "^1.1.1",
        "should": "^7.0.1",
        "supertest": "^1.0.1"
      }
    }
```

```
Tried above methods but returns some WAR and ERR
```

[image: please see the error]

Thanks in ADVANCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the npm modules used as dev dependencies are outdated. That's why you get the WARN messages.

Regarding the ERR, there might be no release with version 2.6.0 available anymore for the accessibility-developer-tools. Modify it's version in your package.json file to 2.10.0 (latest version at this moment) and see if it works.

Update

After fiddling with the package.json you provided, I wasn't able to make the `npm install --only=dev` work on my linux machine due to about 938475938475 errors I kept getting.

I noticed that the mean version you use is 0.4.0 which is quite old. I recommend you to use the current version, by following the [installation steps from the original repository](https://github.com/meanjs/mean)

After I issued the `npm install` on the cloned repository and after it installed what appeared to be the whole npmjs ecosystem, the app worked.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no dependency in the name of accessibility-developer-tools. thanks for ur reply

Comment: Can you then please update your question with the content of package.json?

Comment: package.json added in qns

Comment: $ git clone https://github.com/meanjs/mean.git meanjs
Cloning into 'meanjs'...
remote: Counting objects: 8653, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 8653 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 8639
Receiving objects: 100% (8653/8653), 2.60 MiB | 10.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4387/4387), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
rajesh@rajesh-PC MINGW64 ~/app3
$ cd meanjs
rajesh@rajesh-PC MINGW64 ~/app3/meanjs (master)
$ npm install        ....WAITED 4 MORE THAN 30 MINS NO RESPONSE. my internet speed is slow so may be thats reason?